# Java Runtime Command Line process isn't formatted properly

Tags: java, runtime

On running `man` with almost any command to return the manual of a terminal command, Runtime Execution seems to return few letters in word doubled

Expected

```
OPTIONS
       Note  that,  in  order  to  support obsolescent hardware, unzip's usage
       screen is limited to 22 or 23 lines and should therefore be  considered
       only  a  reminder  of  the basic unzip syntax rather than an exhaustive
       list of all possible flags.  The exhaustive list follows:
```

The output returned by java runtime execution

```
OOPPTTIIOONNSS
       Note  that,  in  order  to  support obsolescent hardware, _u_n_z_i_p's usage
       screen is limited to 22 or 23 lines and should therefore be  considered
       only  a  reminder  of  the basic _u_n_z_i_p syntax rather than an exhaustive
       list of all possible flags.  The exhaustive list follows:
```

The following is my code to get the op from running command

```
String[] cmd = {"man unzip"};
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while (true) {
                line = in.readLine();
                if (line == null) { break; 
                
            }System.out.println(line);
                
                
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime.exec is obsolete.  Use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead.

man pages can contain complex markup, including emphasized text.  man pages are output using an nroff interpreter, which means emphasized text gets rendered as if being sent to an old printer:  an `A` followed by a backspace character followed by another `A` effectively is a double-struck `A`, which a terminal is smart enough to render as a bold character.  Similarly, `_` followed by a backspace character followed by `A` results in an underlined character in the terminal, just as it would on an old printer.

The easiest solution is to pipe the output of `man` through [cat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html).  The nroff interpreter will see that the output destination is another process, rather than a terminal, and will not attempt to render bold or underlined text at all:

```
ProcessBuilder man = new ProcessBuilder("man", "unzip");
ProcessBuilder cat = new ProcessBuilder("cat");

man.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
cat.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
cat.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

Iterable<Process> processes =
    ProcessBuilder.startPipeline(List.of(man, cat));

for (Process process : processes) {
    process.waitFor();
}
```

Note the use of `redirectOutput` and `redirectError`.   When given an argument of INHERIT, those methods cause the standard output and standard error, respectively, of any process created by a ProcessBuilder to appear in the program’s own standard output or standard error.  This removes the need to explicitly read the output and print it.

In Java 8, ProcessBuilder.startPipeline and List.of are not available.  A Java 8 compatible way to accomplish this is to use a shell for the pipeline:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "man unzip | cat");
builder.inheritIO();

Process process = build.start();
process.waitFor();
```

In this case, [inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) performs the same function as `redirectOutput(INHERIT)` and `redirectError(INHERIT)` combined:  the external process’s standard output and standard error appear in the Java process’s own standard ouput and standard error, so there is no need to read and print the output explicitly.

Comment: Also doesn't `man unzip | col` do the same thing, i found it just now